# ISC_Core.js generation

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I'm developing a web application with SmartGWT and I found an issue with Chrome. To solve the issue I modify part of my /war/projectName/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js. Following is the code I modify:

```
isc.Browser.isDOM?"
if(event.target.id.indexOf(\"Geoviewer_\") != -1){return true;}
if(returnVal==false)event.preventDefault();else if(returnVal==isc.EH.STOP_BUBBLING)event.stopPropogation();":"")+"return returnVal;"
```

The second line is the one I add to make the code work under specific circumstances in Chrome.
Now, unfortunately this is not a very 'clean' solution as I have to make the modification after the compilation because the file is generated after it. So my question is how can I find the piece of Java in the GWT code that is generating this Javascript so as to modify it once for ever and have the project compiling right without the necessity of further modifications?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The `ISC_` Javascript files aren't being generated by GWT. SmartGWT is just a wrapper between GWT and a native Javascript library (SmartClient); it's basically the equivalent of a JNI AWT toolkit interface. If you have a repeatable bug, contact Isomorphic; they're pretty good about addressing demonstrable issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't understand one thing though: if it is not generated by gwt, why every time I compile the project my modifications are deleted?

Comment: The GWT build treats it as a resource, just like an image, and copies it over into your output directory every time you launch.

Comment: So how could I modify it once for ever?

Comment: It's really a bad idea to, but if you insist on doing so, you'll need to find where it's copying from (I don't remember, but I think there's a SmartGWT jar) and modify that.

Comment: I understand, even for me is a bad idea but I can't find a better way. This file is generating an anonymous JS function which in Chrome doesn't allow me to click on a flash object. I'd love to find a better solution but up to now I can't see any...